# Sql select query to create a leader board with positional values

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a query that I am using to make a leader board for an android application that will grab data out of an Sql database and order by score. Although with this I want to add the rankID which is a primary field as a positional value in this leader board. How would I go about doing this so I have it ordered by score and have positions in descending order?

```
        String selectQuery = "SELECT rankID, firstName, lastName, score " +
            "FROM leader " +
             "ORDER BY score DESC  " +
             "LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Which database is it? You tagged it with both SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: Where is the database? Is it local or remote?

Comment: Its SQLite I thought I had tagged that must have made a mistake. Its local the database is leader.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql

```
SELECT @rankID:= @rankID +1, firstname, lastname, score
FROM leader,
(SELECT @rankID:= 0) r 
ORDER BY score DESC 
LIMIT     0,10;
```

I would probably just loop it myself in my code and use that as my counter instead of doing it this way though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you're misplacing the order by columns. If you require ordering by KEYWORD_TEXT  then by  BID_AMOUNT  and CITY (if yes then)

Change order by as:

```
 ORDER BY KEYWORD_TEXT, BID_AMOUNT  CITY
```